# How can I remove Host Instance Zombies from BTMessageBox

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

After moving most of our BT-Applications from BizTalk 2009 to BizTalk 2010 environment, we began the work to remove old applications and unused host. In this process we ended up with a zombie host instance.

This has resulted in that the bts_CleanupDeadProcesses startet to fail with error “Executed as user: RH\sqladmin. Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.int_ProcessCleanup_ProcessLabusHost'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 2812).  The step failed.”

After looking at the CleanupDeatProcess process, I found the zombie host instance found in the BTMsgBox.ProcessHeartBeats table, with dtNextHeartbeatTime set to the time when the host was removed.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that the Host Instance Processes don't exist in your services any longer, and that the SQL Agent job fails)

From looking at the source of the `[dbo].[bts_CleanupDeadProcesses]` job, it loops through the `dbo.ProcessHeartbeats` table with a cursor (`btsProcessCurse`, lol) looking for 'dead' hearbeats.

Each process instance has its own cleanup sproc `int_ProcessCleanup_[HostName]` and a sproc for the heartbeat watchdog to call, viz `bts_ProcessHeartbeat_[HostName]` (although FWR the SPROC calls it @ApplicationName), filtered by `WHERE (s.dtNextHeartbeatTime < @dtCurrentTime)`.

It is thus tempting to just delete the record for your deleted / zombie host (or, if you aren't that brave, to simply update the Next `dtNextHeartbeatTime` on the heartbeat record for your dead host instance to sometime next century). Either way, the SQL agent job should skip the dead instances.

An alternative could be to try and re-create the Host and Instances with the same name through the Admin Console, just to delete them (properly) again. This might however cause additional problems as BizTalk won't be able to create the 2 SPROCs above because of the undeleted objects.

However, I wouldn't obviously do this on your prod environment until you've confirmed this works with a trial run first.

It looks like someone else got stuck with a similar situation [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/biztalkgeneral/thread/7928fd98-696b-4aaf-b5b4-a98a8d178ccf)

And there is also a good dive into the details of how the heartbeat mechanism works by XiaoDong Zhu [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2009/11/25/how-does-biztalk-detect-if-a-host-instance-is-dead-in-bts2k6-2k6r2-and-2k9.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Recreating the host worked the on the second attempt.

First time recreating the host, I got to occurrences of the host. After modifying the dtNextHeartBeat and recreating the host a second time. I only had one occurrence of the host, and could delete it from the BizTalk Admin console to get rid of the host.

Comment: I would suggest that you run this past MS PSS - I wouldn't want you to go out of support for the product as a whole by correcting these zombie records. This would also suggest that the upgrade process isn't exactly clean and you might want to file a bug so this issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried BTSTerminator?  That works for one-off cleanups.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2846